# Can't see video files in NFS Share (haneWIN)

Tags: streaming-video, nfs, shared-libraries, osmc

Running OSMC RC3 on RPi2. Just set up NFS server using haneWIN and the instructions here (http://forum.osmc.tv/showthread.php?tid=6285).

I can see the shared folder and subfolders, but I do not see any of the video files and they are all .mkv files in H.264 format. In any case, I would think I should be able to see the files even if the format is wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=197983) link, you should check file permissions and naming conventions.